# Viewing a PGP signature on a Maven artifact

Tags: maven, pgp, gnupg

I'd like to manually verify the PGP signature on a Maven artifact from Central, but I don't know where to start.

I see on Apache's [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) that it says "we require you to provide PGP signatures for all your artifacts".

And I've seen that Sonatype's Nexus Pro software mentions verifying signatures in a [blog post on Nexus Pro features](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/04/nexus-133-introduces-automatic-signature-verification-to-maven-artifacts/)

But I can't find any information on how to get the signatures manually.  I'm familiar enough with GPG to perform the actual verification.  How do I get a `.asc` file for an artifact in Central?

Comment: Related Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3307146/194894) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34795359/194894).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simple download those artifacts (.asc) files and manually check the signature. Maven Central is accessible via http like this:

```
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/soebes/smpp/smpp/0.4/smpp-0.4.pom.asc
```

Comment: OK, unpacking your answer a bit:
For a dependency of `<dependency>
    <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>`
The URL for the signature of the JAR artifact would be 
`http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=x/y/z/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.jar.asc`
Great!  I had been looking under http://mvnrepository.com and not finding any signatures.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check all pgp signatures of your project dependency automatically, you can try execute:

```
mvn org.simplify4u.plugins:pgpverify-maven-plugin:check
```

This plugin downloads all signature (.asc) files and needed pgp key to do signature check.

There is another goal `show` in `pgpverify-maven-plugin`, so if you want only see signature you can execute:

```
mvn org.simplify4u.plugins:pgpverify-maven-plugin:show -Dartifact=junit:junit:4.12
```

More info about this plugin you can find on site:
https://www.simplify4u.org/pgpverify-maven-plugin/