# Verifying providing entities on the Maven Central Repository

Tags: java, maven, security, dependencies

Is there any way we can see for ourselves the entity that provides a dependency on the Maven Central Repository?

For example, if we look for the *javax.xml.bind* dependency on the Maven Central Repository (see [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=javax.xml.bind.)), it's not clear to me who has provided these different artifacts. I would think as a *javax* package one of them should be provided by Oracle?

I can see that are some guidelines (see [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/producers.html)) for producers provided by Sonatype. This suggests that Sonatype ensures the domain is owned by the entity, or that the entity is the "designated maintainer" for the relevant group ID. Is there any way to see which entities Sonatype has assigned to each group ID?

Edit: After reading Robert's comment and [this](http://branchandbound.net/blog/security/2012/08/verify-dependencies-using-pgp/) article I was able to get a better understanding of how the Maven Central Repository uses PGP to achieve this goal. I downloaded the .asc file by adding .asc to the end of the dependency URL.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar.asc

And I could then run this command and get the below output:

*gpg --auto-key-locate keyserver --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --keyserver-options auto-key-retrieve --verify jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar.asc jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar*

*gpg: Signature made Mon, Jul 31, 2017  9:27:23 PM AUSEST
gpg:                using RSA key 3575E1C767076CA8
gpg: Good signature from "Oracle TopLink Dev Team topdev_cz@oracle.com" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.*

Although that doesn't guarantee that "Oracle TopLink Dev Team" is the entity they claim to be (which is where the PGP "web of trust" comes into it), I am at least sure I have a file provided by an entity who signed with that ID and that the file hasn't been changed since it was signed.

Comment: The first question which comes into my mind: What is the purpose of your research? Is there a problem you want to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise Verifying the authenticity of a software library is important as otherwise you may use modified or malware infected libraries in a project which could in the end lead to a serious security incident.

Comment: If you directly look into the file system of the repo you will find `.asc` files which are GPG signatures: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/ For more details see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10804746/150978

Comment: Thanks Robert, I've edited my post.

Comment: I try to build some of "web of trust" for map key to maven artifact, the project is at: https://github.com/s4u/pgp-keys-map